# Dynamic socket.io connection for NGRX effects

Tags: angular, socket.io, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am new of Angular and ngrx so my question could be either very easy or totally wrong. I am developing an app that should receive data from a socket.io server and the url is parametrized: there is a dropdown that allow user to choose which data to see.

I am looking at [this repository](https://github.com/avatsaev/angular-contacts-app-example) but I do not understand how should I modify `src/app/views/contacts/services/contacts-socket.service.ts` and `src/app/views/contacts/store/contacts-effects.ts` to instantiate the socket service and related effects only after the "selection action" is fired.

I think that the socket service should have a paremtrized constructor and not be injected in `ContactEffects` but created afterwards (probably inside an effect related to the "selection action"?); how should I instatiate the effects inside another effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically instantiate effects another effect, you could try [`EffectSources.addEffects(effectsClassInstance)`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/effect_sources.ts#L42-L44)

```js
addEffects(effectSourceInstance: any): void {
  this.next(effectSourceInstance);
}
```